# I want to read some integers from a file it runs fine but it save 0 in the array instead of the other numbers I want to get

Tags: c++, arrays, c, operating-system, filereader

so my function goes like this which i'm calling in the main

the text in file

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

the result:

```
No of Rows : 2
The Contents of File are given below :
0  0  0
0  0  0
```

can someone help me please!!!

the code

```
#include<sdtio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int runningProcess[10];
int lockedProcess[10];
int waitingProcess[10];
int numOfRows=1;
void fileReading(){
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen("test.txt","r");
    char c;
    for (c = getc(fptr); c != EOF; c = getc(fptr)){
        // Increment count if this character is newline
        if (c == '\n'){
            numOfRows = numOfRows + 1;
        } 
    }
    printf("No of Rows : %d\n",numOfRows);
    
    for(int i=0; i<numOfRows;i++){
        fscanf(fptr, "%d* %d* %d*", &runningProcess[i], &lockedProcess[i], &waitingProcess[i]);   
    }
    printf("The Contents of File are given below :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  %d  %d\n", runningProcess[i],lockedProcess[i],waitingProcess[i]);
    }
    fclose(fptr); 
}c
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags. C and C++ are two different languages. Choose one. Judging from your code this is C, not C++.

Comment: `char c;` ==> `int c;`

Comment: `for (c = getc(fptr); c != EOF; c = getc(fptr))` That will leave the stream position at the end of the file. Call `rewind(fptr)` to get it back to the beginning of the file before attempting to parse it.

Comment: `fscanf(whatever)` ==> `if (fscanf(whatever) != <expected_result>) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: `"%d* %d* %d*"` needs to match three `*` characters in the file, but the example file doesn't have any.

Comment: Instead of counting the lines of input and using this as a `for` loop condition, I suggest to use a different loop that counts the number of records while reading (trying to read) the data with `fscanf` until the return value tells you that it could not read 3 values. After this, use a combination of the return value and `feof` and/or `ferror` to decide if you reached EOF or found an error. Note that the counted number of lines does not guarantee that you can successfully read the same number of input records. If you have a line with 2 numbers, `fscanf` would read a number from the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Your algo is not very rigid. But  I won't fix that.
Your problem is that your file has reached the end when you were counting lines.
You can close the file then open it again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int runningProcess [10];
int lockedProcess  [10];
int waitingProcess [10];
int numOfRows = 0;

void main () {
    FILE* fptr;
    fptr = fopen ("test.txt", "r");
    char c;
    for (c = getc (fptr); c != EOF; c = getc (fptr)) {
        // Increment count if this character is newline
        if (c == '\n') {
            numOfRows = numOfRows + 1;
        }
    }
    printf ("No of Rows : %d\n",numOfRows);

    // Close the file and re-open it...
    fclose (fptr);
    fptr = fopen ("test.txt", "r");

    for (int i=0; i<numOfRows; i++) {
        fscanf (fptr, "%d %d %d", &runningProcess[i], &lockedProcess[i], &waitingProcess[i]);
    }
    printf ("The Contents of File are given below :\n");
    for (int i=0; i<numOfRows; i++) {
        printf ("%d  %d  %d\n", runningProcess[i], lockedProcess[i], waitingProcess[i]);
    }
    fclose (fptr);
}
```

TEST:

```
❯ ./readfile
No of Rows : 2
The Contents of File are given below :
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

Comment: @kaylum and pmg  thankyou I used rewind  and I had an error while reading and storing I used  "%d*" which after "%d" solved it. Thankyou dear coding community :)